# Show "Activity Monitor" in every "Desktop"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, desktop, activity-monitor

I find much joy in monitoring my Apple computer's fan roll through monitoring CPU use.

However, I don't know how to make multiple "Activity Monitor" windows, each for one of my "Desktop"s.

I normally fought that by staying in "Desktop 1" as much as possible. However there are moments when I really really need several "Desktop"s, while at the same time being monitoring CPU use.

Got ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start Activity Monitor and an icon will show up in the Dock. Right-click the icon and you'll get a popup with one of the lists of actions is Options. Click on Options and select "All Desktops".

[image]

Comment: Oooooh yesss! ...as I'm in a 13 inches macbook, I think my Dock has to be right sided and always hidden unless hovered. That has been for so long, it just didn't pop off my head.

Comment: @uprego Doesn't work in macOS Mojave.

Comment: @NimeshNeema works in as late as Mojave `10.14.5`. You must be at a later Mojave which removed the feature.

Comment: @uprego I am on 10.14.5. Do you need to press/hold any key when right clicking on the Dock icon? Any other setting that needs to be enabled for the Assign To sub menu to appear? I am not getting the Assign To submenu.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I dunno what's the "Assign To" sub you refer to. My Dock is hidden auto appear on hover. If I click an **open** (maybe is important?) application, I can see almost the same as shown in the pic at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362647/146438. Without having to press or hold any keyboard key. 

Comment: @NimeshNeema Alright I got it. I removed all my "Desktop"s but one, and the "Assign To" sub you say, I found it, **then** doesn't appear.

Comment: @NimeshNeema you can create "Desktop"s by activating/opening "mission control", then hover the upmost border of the display, then find a plus (+) symbol, and click it, it should create one or many additional "Desktop"s.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Then the "Assign To" re/appears. However, those icons seem not to be clickable when "mission control" is active/open.

Comment: @uprego Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I got it. I use an external display connected to my MacBook and use separate Spaces for both displays. I didn't have any additional Space created on either of the displays. I got the Assign To submenu after creating an additional Space. Thanks again for your efforts :)